# getX() not working for button?

Tags: android, button, coordinate

I used the following method for getting x and y values of my button.It returns 0 always.What might be the problem ?

```
btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
             {
                  @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) 
                 {
                       int x = (int)btn_show.getX();
                       int y=  (int)btn_show.getY();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button x is......"+x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button y is......"+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
     }
               });
```

I used this method to pass the value to another activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomDialogExample.class);
                    i.putExtra("value",popup_height);
                    startActivity(i);
```

And this method to retrieve the value

```
Intent i = getIntent();
         int intValue = i.getIntExtra("value", 0);
```

Finally this to set my popup position

```
Window window = customizeDialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
            wlp.y =intValue;
            window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

The variable intValue returns 0 always

Comment: you can get it through on Touch event for button.

Comment: I tried this code in a sample app.Its working properly.But when i use this in my project,it always returns 0.Why so ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
btn_show.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button x is......"+x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button y is......"+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

  return false;
  }
  });
```

Comment: Your wel come!! Glad to help you!!

Comment: I want to pass this y value to another activity and set this value as the y position for my dialog box.I tried to achieve this using intent.But its not working.Could u please tell me how to do this ?Please see updated question...

Comment: It will be always zero because you have by default get as 0. and after that you didn't change button position. So every time you will get same co-ordinates. so will get 0 as always.

Comment: you can simply use another int variables in your second Activity. Or when you are getting data through intent then by default get some other value instead of 0 for both X and Y.

Comment: I want to set this same y value as my dialog's y position.Please see the code snippet.Can u tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Just print that x and Y value in log and just check what is the value of it. and pass that value via intent and by default get that value instead of 0.

Comment: ok.But there is a change.i made a calculation from the obtained y value by adding it to the button height and got a new resultant height.This is the value i want to pass through the intent.no need of x and y.That is the "popup_height" which i passed through the intent.What now ?

Comment: can u help me please ?

Comment: nothing. u have to pass popup_height to new activity.

Answer (score 2):

You put the 'measuring' in the onWindowFocusChanged()-method.
As the documentation states:

This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user.

You could also put it in the onResume() which is the last step before the application is completely on screen and active, however:

Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a game).

If the window/view has not yet been displayed there is no guarantee that it has its measurements, thus the previous method would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do this first

```
Log.d("Button","Button description :"+btn_show.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing float value as it returned by getX() and getY(). the problem might be with integer conversion. I tried your code and its working fine with me. check with your layout.